# Split sorted collection of numbers by interruption in sequence

Tags: c#, .net

How to split a sorted collection of numbers by interruption in sequence?

eg.:

```
List<int> someList = new List<int>{1,2,3,7,8,9}
```

output:

```
someDictionary[0].Key == 1;
someDictionary[0].Value == 3;

someDictionary[1].Key == 7;
someDictionary[1].Value == 9;
```

Comment: It could be me, but I have no idea what you're asking, clarify a bit more?

Comment: how to split sorted list of numbers into other lists where numbers will be continuous. eg. list1 - 1,2,3 , list2 - 7,8,9 , etc.

Comment: Still not getting it.  Can you edit the question with detailed information of the transformation that needs to take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly something like this may do the trick

```
    private static List<List<int>> splitBySeq(List<int> someList)
    {
        //Stores the result
        List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

        //Stores the current sequence
        List<int> currentLst = new List<int>();
        int? lastNumber = null;

        //Iterate the items
        for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
        {
            //If the have a "break" in the sequence and this isnt the first item
            if (lastNumber != null && someList[i] != lastNumber + 1)
            {
                result.Add(currentLst);
                currentLst = new List<int>();
            }

            currentLst.Add(someList[i]);
            lastNumber = someList[i];
        }

        if (currentLst.Count != 0)
            result.Add(currentLst);

        return result;
    }
```